# Issues with yii2-advanced functional tests

Tags: yii2, functional-testing, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I am trying to run tests on the yii2-advanced-app off Yii 2.0.9

When I bootstrap the tests and run the basic default functional tests, I get the following error.

```
Tests\codeception\backend.functional Tests (1) -------------
E LoginCept: Ensure login page works
------------------------------------------------------------
1) LoginCept: Ensure login page works
 Test  .\functional\\LoginCept.php

  [yii\base\ErrorException] Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME


Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->amOnPage("/backend/index.php/site/login")

#1  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:642
#2  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:602
#3  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:720
#4  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:670
#5  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\UrlManager.php:231
#6  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:180
#7  C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:75
#8  C:\Users\Aire\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\browser-kit\Client.php:315
#9  Codeception\Module\Yii2->amOnPage
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mtnt-2\tests\codeception\backend\_support\_generated\FunctionalTesterActions.php:554


Time: 4.55 seconds, Memory: 12.25MB

There was 1 error:

---------

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

#### What I have *learned* so far...

I tried tracing the error and I realized the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is set in the `bootstrap.php` and in the `config/functional.php`. This entry script is correctly set to the `/backend/web/index-test.php`. However, the `index-test.php` file loads the codeception configuration for the acceptance suite.

#### What I have *tried* so far...

I added a new file to `/backend/web` called `index-functional-test.php`. In there, I changed the line which loaded the configuration for the acceptance suite to that of the functional suite. I had the tests use this new entry file, but I still get the same error.

I get the same issue when trying to test both the `/backend` and the `/frontend`. This is what informed this attempt

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12042#issuecomment-236158380) on the corresponding issue raised, this should be fixed when the new yii-app-advanced is pushed.

Basically, the tests are now decentralized. Each app folder would have its own tests folder. It is a structural change to the yii-app-advanced template. You do not have to wait for the Yii team. You can implement decentralized tests yourself.

1. Descend to the each app folder (backend, frontend, common, console, and others)
2. run `./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap -ns "{app}\tests"`. So for the backend, you would run `./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap -ns "backend\tests"`
3. Make sure that the Yii modules are configured correctly.
4. Run tests